# How to hide a div by default when page loads with one radio button selected in angular 2

Tags: angular2-directives

This is `angular` component:
How to set function in component to hide `div` by default when page is loaded. `div` Should be loaded only on clicking the `radio-button`.

```
`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

  templateUrl: './radio-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./radio-test.component.css']
})

export class RadioTestComponent {
  private selectedLink: string="Radio1";          
  setradio(e: string): void  
  {  
    this.selectedLink = e;        
  }   
    isSelected(name: string): boolean   
  {  
      if (!this.selectedLink) {
        return false;  
  }        return (this.selectedLink === name); 
  }  


}

`
```

In `Html`:
How to call function from component so that by default no `div` should be displayed.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="radio">  
            <label>  
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Radio" (click)="setradio('Radio1')" >  
                Radio 1  
            </label>  
        </div>  
        <div class="radio">  
            <label>  
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" (click)="setradio('Radio2')" ngModel>  
                Radio 2 
            </label>  
        </div>  


<div *ngIf="isSelected('Radio1')" >  
     <div style="height:52px;width:300px;background-color: grey;">Radio button 1 is selected </div> 
   </div>  

   <div *ngIf="isSelected('Radio2')">  
     <div style="height:52px;width:300px;background-color: lightgrey;">Radio button 2 is selected </div>  
   </div>   

</div>
```

Comment: Why u using function,You can simply do without using function

Comment: ** how can i do it without function. And Function is for displaying Div on click **

Comment: My understanding is, To show the div when radio button clicked .right?

Comment: when radio button is checked div should display and its working fine. But i want when page is loaded then no div should display. It should only be displayed on click of radio button.

Comment: My answer may help you

Comment: Actually i have to use it in my component class but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app.html**

```
 <div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="radio">  
     <label>  
      <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="model.btn" name="btn" value="btn1"  
 [checked]="model.btn == btn1" >  Radio 1  
     </label>  
  </div>  
  <div class="radio">  
     <label>  
      <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="model.btn" name="btn" value="btn2"
[checked]="model.btn == btn2">  
            Radio 2 
     </label>  
  </div>  


 <div  *ngIf="model.btn=='btn1'" >  
     <div style="height:52px;width:300px;background-color: grey;">Radio button 1 
      is selected </div> 
     </div>  
  <div  *ngIf="model.btn=='btn2'">  
     <div style="height:52px;width:300px;background-color: lightgrey;">Radio 
     button 2 is selected </div>  
     </div>   
 </div>
```

**app.ts**

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  @Component({
     templateUrl: './radio-test.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./radio-test.component.css']
    })

export class RadioTestComponent {
 model:any;
 constructor(){
      this.model=new Button();
      this.model.btn ='btn1';
  }
   }

class Button {
    btn: string
     }
```

Comment: @ReetikaSharma  U can use like this in your component,updated

Comment: How can i set radio button checked.

Comment: @ReetikaSharma You can use  `[checked]="model.btn == btn1"` Within your radio button input elements and make the value of model.btn as btn1 in your constructor

Comment: Its Checked but Div is also displaying.

Comment: @ReetikaSharma Yes.

Comment: i want this div hidden but button checked.

Comment: @ReetikaSharma I dont think that is a good idea.What is your requirement

Comment: @ReetikaSharma This is not the context to talk about file download,ask relevant doubts about your question.if u want to know,ask as a new question,otherwise  u may down voted.

Comment: Actually iam done with this above task your solution worked. Now I am working on file dowloading that's why i asked.